# generate matrix in MAXIMA using an existing matrix

Tags: maxima

I have a matrix a:matrix([1,2],[3, 4]) and b:matrix([1, 0],[0, 1]);
And I would like to define a new bigger matrix C,

where C : ([a, b],[b, a]).

How can I do this in MAXIMA

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'mat_unblocker'. To see documentation, enter

```
? mat_unblocker
```